# Unit testing a generic query factory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, ninject

I have implemented a command/query architecture for a project I am working on, but am having trouble testing my classes that require use of the associated factories. The basis of my architecture can be found here: https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92

In particular, I have something similar to the following

```
public interface IQueryFactory
{
    TQuery CreateQuery<TQuery, TResult>() 
        where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>;
}

public interface IQuery<TResult>
{
} 

public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Execute(TQuery query);
}

public interface IQueryHandlerFactory
{
    IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> CreateQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>()
        where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>;
}

public class GetFooDataQuery : IQuery<IEnumerable<FooData>>
{   
    public int FooId { get; set; }
}

public class GetFooQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<GetFooDataQuery, IEnumerable<FooData>>
{        
    private readonly IFooRepository _fooRepository;

    public GetFooDataQueryHandler(IFooRepository fooRepository)
    {          
        _fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FooData> Execute(GetFooDataQuery query)
    {           
        return    _fooRepository.Foo.Where(x => x.fooId > query.FooId).ToList();            
    }
}
```

My classes that need to query the database have a constructor that includes a query factory and a query handler factory. Everything gets wired up via Ninject.

It works fine, but I am finding it difficult to create Unit tests for any class that includes query factories as I need to include the factories as part of the constructor. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test repository that implements IFooRepository and pass that to the constructor for GetFooQueryHandler.  Since it is your test class, you can set it to known test values for the purposes to testing code that depends on this.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var x = new GetFooQueryHandler(new TestFooRepository
        {
            Foo = new List<FooData>()
        });
    var result = x.Execute(new GetFooDataQuery { FooId = 45 });

}

class TestFooRepository : IFooRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<FooData> Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough in my question, i apologize.  Where I am having trouble is in testing the classes that rely on a query and query handler.

Their constructors require a QueryHandlerFactory and a QueryFactory. I need to be able to instantiate/mock those in order to test the business logic.

I am having trouble though creating  test classes for IQueryHandlerFactory and IQueryFactory

Comment: If the code you are testing doesn't actually use that dependency, just pass a null.  If it does use the dependency, you will need to create the test class for those interfaces.  What problems are you having creating those classes?  If you right-click on the interface in your test class and select "Implement Interface", does it implement something you can use?